# Is there a yum or apt-get like system on Solaris?

Tags: package-management, solaris

I am aware of the use of `pkg` to install an individual package file, but it does not include a repository infrastructure like other Linux distributions. Is there any solution that behaves like `yum` or `apt on the Solaris 11 Express platform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solaris IPS (Image Packaging System) is definitely based on a repository infrastructure and behaves like yum/apt if you mean automatically handles dependencies.

You can list the publisher's repositories with this command:

```
pkg publisher
```

You can add and remove publishers and you can also create your own repository.

More details [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/technologies/ips-323421.html)

Comment: ISR that pkg does not do any dependency management?

Comment: @symcbean : What do you mean "ISR" ?

Comment: @symcbean You must be remembering the old SVR4 packaging system from Solaris 10 and earlier.  Solaris 11 pkg absolutely does dependency management.

Comment: @alanc: Thanks (Solaris skills a bit rusty here).

Comment: @symcbean: okay, so I guess ISR was for "I seem to recall/remember"

Answer (score 2):

[OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/) (open fork of Blastwave) allows you to use pkgutil to install software from their repositories. E.g. `pkgutil --install coreutils`

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sunfreeware](http://sunfreeware.com/).  The [DryDog](http://sun.drydog.com/packages.php) site has a good bit, with links to others.

Comment: Note: Sunfreeware hasn't been free since Sept 30, 2013